# Specify Google Cloud Storage for Google Analaytics Unsampled Reports

Tags: google-analytics-api

Unsampled Reports can be stored in either Google Cloud Storage or Google Drive, I want to specify Google Cloud Storage as default storage instead of Google Drive.

How do I do it, there isn't a option given in the example they have provided at [Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports/insert)

```
reports = analytics.management().unsampledReports().insert(
  accountId='123456',
  webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
  profileId='7654321',
  body={
      'title': 'A test Report',
      'start-date': '2013-01-01',
      'end-date': '2013-01-31',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:bounces',
      'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
      'filters': 'ga:bounces>=100',
      'segment': 'gaid::-1'
  }
```

).execute()

On success the **resource** returned is of the form,

```
{
    "id": string,
    "kind": "analytics#unsampledReport",
    "selfLink": string,
    "title": string,
    "accountId": string,
    "webPropertyId": string,
    "profileId": string,
    "start-date": string,
    "end-date": string,
    "metrics": string,
    "dimensions": string,
    "filters": string,
    "segment": string,
    "status": string,
    "downloadType": string,
    "driveDownloadDetails": {
        "documentId": string
     },
   "cloudStorageDownloadDetails": {
        "bucketId": string,
        "objectId": string
     },
    "created": datetime,
    "updated": datetime
  }
```